# Insert Mapbox in Facebook App

Tags: javascript, facebook, http, facebook-apps, mapbox

I'm trying to create a Facebook App that use a Mapbox Map, but in my first test I found a problem, js error console:

[blocked] The page at https://xxx-7388.herokuapp.com/?fb_source=appcenter&fb_appcenter=1#/games ran insecure content from http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/xxx.map-e4gilw29.jsonp?callback=grid.

I think that the problem is the call that mapbox.layer() does to recive the map tails png from MapBox api:

```
    var map = mapbox.map('map');
    map.addLayer(mapbox.layer().id('xxx.map-e4gilw29'));
```

In this moment I create a app with heroku template of ruby facebook app.

Do you think that without a https call on MapBox api is not possible resolve the problem? Or that is not possible resolve the problem without use of a iframe that will contains the map and my application?

Someone has encountered the same problem, or similar?
You have any suggestions?

Thanks for attention. Best Regards. (sorry for my english)
Alberto

Answer (score 0):

Answered this over in http://support.mapbox.com/ - you'll need to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an older version of mapbox.js. Are you calling `L.mapbox.map()`? The latest version of MapBox only uses SSL.